# How to select an object shared with my neighbours

Tags: netlogo

I am working on a model where turtles can exchange objects, like a virus, disease or just a ball.
After selected randomly one turtle, this turtle created an object as follows

```
create-object 1[ hide-turtle set new_object self set chosen? false]

  set selected one-of breed1 
  ask selected [
        set attribute random-float 1
        set my-list fput attribute my-list
      ]
```

to put into a list shared between the turtle and its neighbourhood.
Now, what I would like is to consider another option for the same turtle, i.e. to choose one of the (old) items collected in its list based on the items' attribute: the higher the value, the more likely it is to be chosen.

```
 ask one-of breed1 
     let selected-objects objects with [not chosen?]
     let choice rnd:weighted-one-of selected-objects [attribute]
     ask choice [set chosen? true]
     set my-list fput choice my-list
  ]
```

where

```
globals [
  chosen?
  new_object ; in alternative to (list attribute in my-list)
]

breed[breed1 breed_1]
breed[objects object]

breed1-own [
  my-list
  my-list?
  attribute
  choice
]
```

My doubts are:

1. how can I keep this object in 'memory'/in list with its attribute?
   I would need to keep in memory as the turtles (breed1) can exchange/spread the object/virus through time, but potentially this object can change its attribute's value.
2. would it be better to add to the list the object and/or its attribute?
3. if I wanted to change its value, after selected, how could I do?

   Thank you for your time

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK, so you asked

> (1) how can I keep this object in 'memory'/in list with its attribute?
>   I would need to keep in memory as the turtles (breed1) can
>   exchange/spread the object/virus through time, but potentially this
>   object can change its attribute's value.

Once you create them, the objects will persist until you kill them.  This means that the attribute that each object owns will also persist without any effort on your part.

Looking at your code,  you could keep track of which object is chosen by setting the global variable "new_object" to be the **who** number of the object you chose.  .

The object with the given who number can have its attribute changed by anyone, anytime and all the other agents will be able to see that new value.

You also ask:

> (2) would it be better to add to the list the object and/or its
>   attribute?

I would answer, don't put either the object or the attribute of the object on the my-list.    **Put the who number on the my-list.**   From the who number you can find the object with that who number, and from the object you can find the attribute.

OK, so if you do that,  can you sort the list by attribute?  Yes, you can do that with some clever code.  The key line is the one sorting the list by the attribute of the objects which have their who numbers in the list my-list.

```
 let temp2-list sort-on [ attribute ] objects with [ member? who [my-list] of myself ]
```

I think the answer to your third question should be clear now.

> if I wanted to change its value, after selected, how could I do?

Here's working code that should help explain this answer. Setup generates one 
agent and 6 objects and makes up a random my-list and a corresponding list of
attributes.  Go generates sorted lists of objects and attributes.  The object
in the list with the highest attribute is identified.

Note that objects-own [attribute].  You didn't mention that.

The example code is heavily documented in-line.

```
globals [
  chosen_object_who
  acting_breed1_who
]

breed[breed1 breed_1]
breed[objects object]

objects-own
[ attribute ]

breed1-own [
  my-list    ;; list of who numbers of objects, initialize to [] or it may fail
  attr-list  ;; list of attributes of the my-list objects, in the same order

  attribute-of-chosen-object
  who-of-chosen-object

   my-list?  ;; unknown
]

to setup
  clear-all

  print "creating 5 objects"
  create-objects 5 [ set attribute random 100 
  print (word "created object " who " with attribute " attribute )
  ]

  create-breed1 1 [
    set my-list []  
    set attr-list []
    set my-list? false      
    set attribute-of-chosen-object -1   
    set  who-of-chosen-object -1        
  ]

    ask one-of breed1 [
    set acting_breed1_who who

    ;; add six random object to my-list then remove duplicates
    repeat 6 [
                  set my-list fput [who] of one-of objects my-list
             ]
    set my-list remove-duplicates my-list      

    ;; create the list of corresponding attributes
    set attr-list map [i -> [attribute] of object i ] my-list

    print (word "at end of setup, here's the my-list: " my-list )
    print (word "here's the corresponding attr-list : " attr-list )

    print ""
    ]    
    reset-ticks    
end

to go 
ask one-of breed1 [  ;; there is only one for this example

 ;; here's the magic command line  
 let temp2-list sort-on [ attribute ] objects with [ member? who [my-list] of myself ]

 ;; print (word "temp2-list: " temp2-list)

 ;; yields a list like [(object 3) (object 1) (object 4) (object 2) (object 0)]   
 ;; it looks like an agent set but it's actually a list of objects in my-list, 
 ;; but sorted into order by ascending attributes.

 ;; generate the new my-list, in the new order
 set my-list map [i -> [who] of i ] temp2-list 
 set attr-list map [i -> [attribute] of i ] temp2-list 
    print "=========== after sort ====================="
    print (word "sorted my-list now is " my-list)
    print (word "matching attr-list is " attr-list )
    print ""

;; You can select the best choice as the last item in the list, giving you the
;; who number of the object which has the highest attribute value
    let best-choice 999

    if-else length my-list > 0
    [ set best-choice last my-list ]
    [ error " my-list is empty! "]

    ;; saved as a global
    set chosen_object_who best-choice

    ;; also save variables in the breed1 we are looking at now
    set attribute-of-chosen-object last attr-list
    set  who-of-chosen-object      last my-list

    print (word "Assuming we want the object with the highest attribute")
    print ""
    print (word " The best choice object-who is " best-choice )
    print (word " the attribute of that choice is " last attr-list )

    print " "
    print " all set to do something with the chosen object "
    print " the choice is known both locally and globally "
    inspect self
   ]

tick

end
```

Comment: Thank you Wade for your answer and explanation. So you suggested to use the index of the objects. Interesting! Could you please explain me what this part of code does? `;; You can select the best choice as the last item in the list, giving you the
;; who number of the object which has the highest attribute value
    let best-choice 999`. Should it inspect each item until it finds the item with the highest value of attribute?